# How do I provide configuration options for a Ruby makefile? WSL, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby, makefile, openssl

[TL;DR: The solution is installing `libssl-dev`. See my answer to myself, below, which also solves related problems).]

[Original question:] I am trying to update some Ruby gems in a WSL/Ubuntu 20.04 environment. Specifically, I'm trying to update the `openssl` gem. I think I understand the error message and *almost* understand how to solve it. I need to provide the directory to openssl as a configuration option. I just don't know how to do that. Here's the relevant part of the error message:

```sh
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
<snip>
--with-openssl-dir
<snip>
extconf.rb:98:in `<main>': OpenSSL library could not be found. 
You might want to use --with-openssl-dir=<dir> option to specify 
the prefix where OpenSSL is installed. (RuntimeError)
```

Okay, so I understand I should use **`--with-openssl-dir=<dir>`** to provide the path to OpenSSL (which is in `/usr/lib/ssl`).

But **how do I do that?** As I understand it, this is a compilation flag that should go in a makefile or be passed at compile time. But I don't understand what file I should edit to pass this flag. I read the `extconf.rb` file, and to the extent I understand it, I don't see where this flag should go. I also don't see a makefile to edit (and if it's generated dynamically at compile time, that wouldn't be the right approach anyway).

I realize this might be obvious to some, but it's not to me, and I spent a fair amount of time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know how to do what I asked about (pass a flag in a makefile), but I have solved my problem, which is more general than just the `openssl` package, even though that was the one with the clearest error message. The basic issue is that Ruby wants the `-dev` packages installed for `openssl` and several other gems that could not be updated. Here are each of the gems that could not be updated, and how I solved the errors:

- **openssl**

  - error: `extconf.rb:98:in <main>: OpenSSL library could not be found. You might want to use --with-openssl-dir=<dir> option to specify the prefix where OpenSSL is installed. (RuntimeError)`
  - solution:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
sudo gem update openssl
```

- **zlib**

  - error:

```
checking for deflateReset() in -lz... no
checking for deflateReset() in -llibz... no
checking for deflateReset() in -lzlib1... no
checking for deflateReset() in -lzlib... no
checking for deflateReset() in -lzdll... no
checking for deflateReset() in -lzlibwapi... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

- solution:

```
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev
sudo gem update zlib
```

- **fiddle**

  - error: `extconf.rb:87:in '<main>': missing libffi. Please install libffi.`
  - solution:

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
sudo gem update fiddle
```

- **net-pop** and **net-smtp**

  - These both failed with the same error message, which was actually pretty informative: `The last version of io-wait (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 0.1.0. Try installing it with gem install io-wait -v 0.1.0 and then running the current command again`
  - Solution:

```
sudo gem install io-wait -v 0.1.0 
sudo gem update net-pop
sudo gem update net-smtp
```

- **readline-ext**

  - Again, the error message was fairly informative: `Neither readline nor libedit was found (RuntimeError)`
  - Solution:

```
sudo apt install libreadline-dev 
sudo apt install libedit-dev
sudo gem update readline-ext
```

Note: I understand that using `sudo` to update the gems system-wide may not be a best practice. But it's what I did. I also understand that some of these error messages may be obvious; that's why I didn't mention them in my first post. But it was solving the `zlib` and `fiddle` problems that clued me in to the solution to the `openssl` problem, so I figured I'd post all this information together, since all the errors arose in the same installation effort.